# An epistemic-logic difference between  and  in deontic logic?

Tags: logic

Although I can imagine arguable counterexamples to this claim, I would tend to think that:

1. **OB***a* → **OB**k**OB***a*

... where "k" is for a generic knowledge operator.

Of the following two strings, the first is the one I'd favor:

2. **PM***a* → **PM**k**PM***a*
3. **PM***a* → **OB**k**PM***a*

Note that **OB***a* → **PM**k**OB***a* follows from (1) and **OB***a* → **PM***a*. However, I'm not sure why we would always be obligated to know whatever is permitted. I can see that there is some relevance in that if something has been substantively disallowed, there is a negative obligation concerning that thing, but as for "mere permission," well... At any rate, (4) seems false:

4. **FR***a* → **FR**k**FR***a*

And so although prohibitions can be framed as negative obligations, making note of that doesn't help, here, since **OB**~*a* → **OB**~k**OB**~*a* still comes across wrong in a way that (1) and (2) don't (even if (1), for example, is wrong, it seems *less* wrong than (4), to me). On the other hand, I can generally imagine that there might be arguable counterexamples to my rejection of (4).

At first, this apparent discrepancy between **OB**/**PM** and **FR** seemed perhaps trivial, but now I wonder if it is useful to make note of in addressing [paradoxes/puzzles of epistemic obligation](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-deontic/supplement.html#ParaEpisObliAqvi1967)?

Comment: This ought to be in Math.SE or Math.OF as its about mathematical logic.

Comment: This ought to be in Philosophy.SE as it's about philosophical logic.